# Docker Desktop Installation failed 4.7.0 (Manifest extraction failed: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe)

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

Docker Desktop 4.7.0 installation fails instantly, log file below.

If I try to download an older version <4.5, then the download will start but after bootup the same error comes to light. My guess is that something is wrong with the *System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe* assembly file.

Any ideas what might actually be causing this and what are possible fixes?

[image: Docker Installation failed image]

Log file:

```
"Version: 4.7.0 (77141)
Sha1: 
Started on: 2022/04/10 15:38:12.555
Resources: C:\Users\Me\Downloads\resources
OS: Windows 10 Home
Edition: Core
Id: 2009
Build: 19044
BuildLabName: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
File: C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\install-log-admin.txt
CommandLine: "C:\Users\Kaur\Downloads\Docker Desktop Installer4.7ERROR.exe" 
You can send feedback, including this log file, at https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues
[2022-04-10T15:38:12.821384600Z][ManifestAndExistingInstallationLoader][Info   ] No install path specified, looking for default installation registry key
[2022-04-10T15:38:12.837008100Z][Installer         ][Info   ] No installation found
[2022-04-10T15:38:13.061938200Z][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Cancel pending background download
[2022-04-10T15:38:13.061938200Z][BackgroundTransfer][Info   ] Cancel current background transfer job
[2022-04-10T15:38:17.390107900Z][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Using package: res:DockerDesktop
[2022-04-10T15:38:17.390107900Z][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Downloading
[2022-04-10T15:38:18.922416300Z][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Extracting manifest
[2022-04-10T15:38:19.029412900Z][InstallWorkflow   ][Error  ] Installation failed System.Exception: Manifest extraction failed: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
   at System.Span`1.Create(T[] array, Int32 start)
   at SharpCompress.Compressors.LZMA.LzmaStream..ctor(Byte[] properties, Stream inputStream, Int64 inputSize, Int64 outputSize, Stream presetDictionary, Boolean isLzma2)
   at SharpCompress.Compressors.LZMA.LzmaStream..ctor(Byte[] properties, Stream inputStream, Int64 inputSize, Int64 outputSize)
   at SharpCompress.Compressors.LZMA.DecoderRegistry.CreateDecoderStream(CMethodId id, Stream[] inStreams, Byte[] info, IPasswordProvider pass, Int64 limit)
   at SharpCompress.Compressors.LZMA.DecoderStreamHelper.CreateDecoderStream(Stream inStream, Int64 startPos, Int64[] packSizes, CFolder folderInfo, IPasswordProvider pass)
   at SharpCompress.Common.SevenZip.ArchiveReader.ReadAndDecodePackedStreams(Int64 baseOffset, IPasswordProvider pass)
   at SharpCompress.Common.SevenZip.ArchiveReader.ReadDatabase(IPasswordProvider pass)
   at SharpCompress.Archives.SevenZip.SevenZipArchive.LoadFactory(Stream stream)
   at SharpCompress.Archives.SevenZip.SevenZipArchive.<LoadEntries>d__11.MoveNext()
   at SharpCompress.LazyReadOnlyCollection`1.LazyLoader.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at CommunityInstaller.ExtractManifestStep.<DoAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
[2022-04-10T15:38:19.032411200Z][InstallWorkflow   ][Info   ] Rollbacking component CommunityInstaller.DownloadStep
[2022-04-10T15:38:19.889337800Z][Installer         ][Warning] Failed to track the installer started event
"
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable Windows Defender.

Workaround
In `Windows Security` under `Virus & threat protection` disable `VIrus & threat protection settings`.

[image]